# SQL Logic - Two Tables, Multiple Rows from Table Two

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I need to retrieve results from two tables. Table A is named 'MEMBERS' and table B is named 'MEMBERUDFS'. I need a LEFT JOIN on the tables because not all rows in 'MEMBERS' will have an entry in 'MEMBERUDFS'. I need to pull the rows from 'MEMBERS' that match the criteria and the same from 'MEMBERUDFS' (not all of the entries in MEMBERUDFS are relevant to this query). This is where I need same help: My current query returns all of the fields from the MEMBERS table and the corresponding rows from MEMBERUDFS resulting in multiple rows for each member. What I would like to do is have the fields from the MEMBERUDFS table returned on the same line as the MEMBERS data. For example, I get:

```
lastname   firstname   relationship   email              entrydate   scancode   sitename   udflabel   udfvalue   expr1   expr2
doe        jane        p              janedoe@gmail.com  1/1/2016    1234       Home       Guest Pass Yes        steve   holmes
doe        jane        p              janedoe@gmail.com  1/1/2016    1234       Home       Pass Used  No         steve   holmes
doe        jane        p              janedoe@gmail.com  1/1/2016    1234       Home       Visited    yes        steve   holmes
```

What I am looking for is this:

```
doe   jane  p  janedoe@gmail.com  1/1/2016    1234   Guest Pass    Yes    steve    holmes     Pass Used     No     Visited     yes
```

The following is my query:

```
SELECT MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.relationship, MEMBERS.email, MEMBERS.entrydate,
       MEMBERS.scancode, MEMBERS.siteid, SITES.sitename, 
       MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udflabel, MEMBERUDFS.udfvalue, EMPLOYEES.lname AS Expr1,
       EMPLOYEES.fname AS Expr2
FROM MEMBERS
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERUDFS.memid
  INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid
  INNER JOIN SITES ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON MEMBERS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P')
  AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
  AND (MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '25' OR
       MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '26' OR
       MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '27')
  AND (MEMBERS.entrydate BETWEEN @entryDateStart AND @entryDateEnd)
ORDER BY MEMBERS.entrydate DESC
```

Comment: Move the MEMBERUDFS.udfid conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause, if you want to get true left join behavior. (As it is now you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: As far as i know this is how joins work, if you do it in the mentioned way, how would you name the extra columns? and what if each member has different amount of related UDF's?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could take.  The easiest one would be to JOIN to the MEMBERUDFS table multiple times, once for each `udfid` that you are trying to retrieve.  A quick bit of sample code is below.

```
SELECT
    MEMBERS.lname
    ,MEMBERS.fname
    ,MEMBERS.relationship
    ,MEMBERS.email
    ,MEMBERS.entrydate
    ,MEMBERS.scancode
    ,MEMBERS.siteid
    ,SITES.sitename
    ,MUS_25.udflabel
    ,MU_25.udfvalue
    ,MUS_26.udflabel
    ,MU_26.udfvalue
    ,MUS_27.udflabel
    ,MU_27.udfvalue
    ,EMPLOYEES.lname AS Expr1
    ,EMPLOYEES.fname AS Expr2
FROM
    MEMBERS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS MU_25
        ON MEMBERS.memid = MU_25.memid AND
            MU_25.udfid = '25'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS MUS_25
        ON MU_25.udfid = MUS_25.udfid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS MU_26
        ON MEMBERS.memid = MU_26.memid AND
            MU_26.udfid = '26'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS MUS_26
        ON MU_26.udfid = MUS_26.udfid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS MU_27
        ON MEMBERS.memid = MU_27.memid AND
            MU_27.udfid = '27'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS MUS_27
        ON MU_27.udfid = MUS_27.udfid
    INNER JOIN SITES
        ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES
        ON MEMBERS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE
    (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P') AND
    (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite) AND
    (MEMBERS.entrydate BETWEEN @entryDateStart AND @entryDateEnd)
ORDER BY
    MEMBERS.entrydate DESC
```

Note that, if your `udfid` is consistent (always has the same label), you could simply alias each `udfvalue` with the appropriate label:

```
SELECT
    MEMBERS.lname
    ,MEMBERS.fname
    ,MEMBERS.relationship
    ,MEMBERS.email
    ,MEMBERS.entrydate
    ,MEMBERS.scancode
    ,MEMBERS.siteid
    ,SITES.sitename
    ,MU_25.udfvalue AS Guest_Pass
    ,MU_26.udfvalue AS Pass_Used
    ,MU_27.udfvalue AS Visited
    ,EMPLOYEES.lname AS Expr1
    ,EMPLOYEES.fname AS Expr2
FROM
    MEMBERS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS MU_25
        ON MEMBERS.memid = MU_25.memid AND
            MU_25.udfid = '25'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS MU_26
        ON MEMBERS.memid = MU_26.memid AND
            MU_26.udfid = '26'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS MU_27
        ON MEMBERS.memid = MU_27.memid AND
            MU_27.udfid = '27'
    INNER JOIN SITES
        ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES
        ON MEMBERS.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
WHERE
    (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P') AND
    (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite) AND
    (MEMBERS.entrydate BETWEEN @entryDateStart AND @entryDateEnd)
ORDER BY
    MEMBERS.entrydate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is often called *pivoting*: converting rows into columns.  It's done with a `case` statement.  You didn't give a clear description of the UDFS table and how you want it laid out, but I can give you an idea of how to go about it,

```
select lname, fname 
       , max( case udfid when 25 then 'foo' end ) as col1
       , max( case udfid when 26 then 'foo' end ) as col2
from MEMBERS left join MEMBERUDFS 
...
group by lname, fname
```

Some DBMSs have a `PIVOT` operator that can make the query a little less verbose or more efficient to execute.  If searching for examples, you should find "fold" and "pivot" discussed together.